# selenium 127.0.0.1 vs localhost using IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple Selenium 2 test for IE9 on Windows 7 Pro PC. It works when I use 127.0.0.1 in the `Navigate().To()` However, when I use localhost it can't find the only element on the page which has an id. I'm getting ElementNotFound.

Now I notice in my hosts file that the mapping for `127.0.0.1  localhost` is commented out. Does this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes uncomment it, alternatively you can ping localhost to see if you are resolving the name properly